# AJAX request failing in jQuery but not in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, rest

I have a RESTful web service (hosted on a different server via IIS) that returns JSON. The strange thing is the following NodeJS command line test application (not via the web browser, but via the command line) is working fine and returning the JSON:

**Working NodeJS App:**

```
var request = require("request");
var btoa = require("btoa");

var uname = "corp\\user.name";
var pword = "password123"

var options = {
    url: "http://192.168.3.142/v1/foo?format=json",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(uname + ":" + pword)
    }
};

request(options, function(err, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

However the following AJAX request fails with:

```
OPTIONS http://192.168.3.142/v1/foo?format=json 401 (Unauthorized) jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.3.142/v1/foo?format=json. Invalid HTTP status code 401
```

This is the response header from the server:

```
Response Headers:

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:1293
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 06 Mar 2014 05:41:24 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="192.168.3.142"
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

**AJAX code:**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        var creds = {
            username: "corp\\user.name",
            password: "password123"
        };
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(creds.username + ":" + creds.password));
        return true;
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://192.168.3.142/v1/foo?format=json",
    success: function (data, text) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Throws the same *401 (Unauthorized)*:

```
var creds = {
    username: "corp\\user.name",
    password: "password123"
};
var credentials = btoa(creds.username + ":" + creds.password);
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text/json",
    url: "http://192.168.3.142/v1/foo?format=json",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
        return true;
    },
    success: function (data, text) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: put the beforeSend into the $.ajax call, and try it without a settings parameter. Instead of computing the "Basic XXXX" string, pre-compute it and pass it in statically. I also noticed your IP address changed, was that intentional? Also, try setting the `dataType` property to `text/json`

Comment: Try those then report back please :)

Comment: @blakev: See updated question. Still throwing a `401 (Unauthorized)` and IP address was unintentional.

Comment: Did u try this way .. -- $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text/json",
    url: "http://192.168.3.142/v1/foo?format=json",    
          headers: {          
                "Authorization", "Basic " + redentials
      },
  success : function(response) {  
       ...  
   } });

Comment: @Neha: Your syntax is wrong.

Comment: @Neha: I think you meant this: `headers: { "Authorization": "Basic " + credentials }` and no that doesn't work either unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I added `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` to the `$.ajaxSetup({});` the error was returning:

`Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is ''. It must be 'true' to allow credentials.`

I added `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` on the server-side and it's now working correctly.

```
var creds = {
    username: "username",
    password: "password"
};
var credentials = btoa(creds.username + ":" + creds.password);
$.ajaxSetup({
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
        return true;
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost/v1/service",
    async: true,
    success: function (data, text) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Had a doubt. If we don't have access to server side code.And the curl request is working properly then how can we fix this issue?